# error with subquery in "if" statement (error code:1241)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, phpmyadmin

There is an error in my query - I think its **logically** true.

> error code 1241 : operand should contain 1 column(s)

`1>0` is just for test! I'll change it in backend with php.

```
SELECT if(1>0,(SELECT
                count(lh_chat.dep_id) as chat_vorodi_be_saf,
                count(lh_chat.online_user_id) as tedad_chat_mojadad,
                count(lh_chat_online_user.rightel_number) as tedad_chat_shomare_yekta,
                count(chat_status.status) as chat_pasokh_dade_shode

                FROM
                  lh_chat
                INNER JOIN
                  lh_chat_online_user
                ON
                   lh_chat.id = lh_chat_online_user.chat_id
                INNER JOIN
                  chat_status
                ON
                  lh_chat.id = chat_status.chat_id where lh_chat.operation_ts between 0 and 1),'')

union all
SELECT if(1>0,(SELECT
                count(lh_chat.dep_id) as chat_vorodi_be_saf,
                count(lh_chat.online_user_id) as tedad_chat_mojadad,
                count(lh_chat_online_user.rightel_number) as tedad_chat_shomare_yekta,
                count(chat_status.status) as chat_pasokh_dade_shode

                FROM
                  lh_chat
                INNER JOIN
                  lh_chat_online_user
                ON
                   lh_chat.id = lh_chat_online_user.chat_id
                INNER JOIN
                  chat_status
                ON
                  lh_chat.id = chat_status.chat_id where lh_chat.operation_ts between 1 and 2),'')

union all
SELECT if(1>0,(SELECT
                count(lh_chat.dep_id) as chat_vorodi_be_saf,
                count(lh_chat.online_user_id) as tedad_chat_mojadad,
                count(lh_chat_online_user.rightel_number) as tedad_chat_shomare_yekta,
                count(chat_status.status) as chat_pasokh_dade_shode

                FROM
                  lh_chat
                INNER JOIN
                  lh_chat_online_user
                ON
                   lh_chat.id = lh_chat_online_user.chat_id
                INNER JOIN
                  chat_status
                ON
                  lh_chat.id = chat_status.chat_id where lh_chat.operation_ts between 2 and 3),'')
```

Comment: What is the full error?

Comment: dear @sagi mysql just displayed this ->  error code 1241 : operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: are you using oracle or mysql ?  i guess mysql

Comment: yeah i'm using mysql @moudiz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the case statement instead of if.

Comment: i have an if it means , the query should be checked before execution

Comment: @daniel.lalasa: That is *not* what `if` means.

Answer (score 1):

this part "if(1>0,(SELECT" must have only one field after SELECT.